# Django EMAIL_PORT in localhost development

Tags: django, email-verification

I am trying to integrate email verification during a new user registration. I am in the beggining of this feature implementation. For this purposes in `settings.py` i set the following settings

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = ????
```

and here is my question which EMAIL_PORT i should specify if i am working on my local computer

Comment: For gmail use 587 as the port number when TLS is true.

Comment: @alamshafi2263 thank you. Where port settings for different systems is located

Comment: For different systems you have to look at the smtp servers port defined port lists. Usually this informations are publicly available for major smtp service providers.

Comment: @alamshafi2263 thank you for this information. If you formating your answers like answer i will flag it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For gmail use 587 when TLS is true.

For other smtp providers look at the smtp servers docs or manuals for their defined port lists. This informations are publicly available for major smtp service providers.

Answer (score 1):

you are using gmail smtp server so you should use port number 587